# Query to get all rows from previous month

Tags: mysql

I need to select all rows in my database that were created last month.

For example, if the current month is January, then I want to return all rows that were created in December, if the month is February, then I want to return all rows that were created in January. I have a `date_created` column in my database that lists the date created in this format: `2007-06-05 14:50:17`.

Answer (score 245, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE YEAR(date_created) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
AND MONTH(date_created) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

Comment: `SELECT * FROM table
WHERE date_created BETWEEN (CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND CURRENT_DATE();`

Comment: @GhazanfarMir your query doesn't quite match the question, whereas the  answer above, does. Yours returns the rows between this day last month through yesterday.

Comment: @MattPassell I am sorry but `between` is inclusive of the boundaries.. It will include current date as well. Why/How it will be limited to yesterday?? Please elaborate?

Comment: I see what you mean.. Yes you are right.. my query isn't what OP wanted.. I misunderstood the question

Comment: what about if the `current_date` it is not today but a random date given from the client?

Comment: @GhazanfarMir its like getting two great answers when 1 question was asked. Thanks just what I was looking for even if op didn't ask

Comment: @hobodave What if I want to get the datas from the first date of the month?

Answer (score 28):

Here's another alternative.  Assuming you have an indexed `DATE` or `DATETIME` type field, this should use the index as the formatted dates will be type converted before the index is used.  You should then see a `range` query rather than an `index` query when viewed with [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/using-explain.html).

```
SELECT
    * 
FROM
    table
WHERE 
    date_created >= DATE_FORMAT( CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH, '%Y/%m/01' ) 
AND
    date_created < DATE_FORMAT( CURRENT_DATE, '%Y/%m/01' )
```

Comment: +1. Much more index friendly. You could also throw a `STR_TO_DATE` around the `DATE_FORMAT` so it is always dealing with date objects.

Comment: I agree, this approach is far quicker to run on a large dataset due to it not using MONTH() and YEAR()

Answer (score 23):

If there are no future dates ...

```
SELECT * 
FROM   table_name 
WHERE  date_created > (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH);
```

Tested.

Comment: I think they were looking for something different. ie All records from last month (ie Oct 1 - Oct 31, 2012 23:59:59).  The query above would return the last ~30 or so days, from today's date and *time*.

Answer (score 18):

Alternatively to [hobodave's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2090235/443779)

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE YEAR(date_created) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
AND MONTH(date_created) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

You could achieve the same with EXTRACT, using YEAR_MONTH as unit, thus you wouldn't need the AND, like so:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM date_created) = EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM CURDATE() - INTERVAL
1 MONTH)
```

Comment: This works great for months, but unfortunately there is no `YEAR_WEEK` [temporal interval](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/expressions.html#temporal-intervals), so you'd have to fall back to hobodave's answer if you need weeks instead of months.

Answer (score 9):

```
SELECT *
FROM  yourtable
where DATE_FORMAT(date_created, '%Y-%m') = date_format(DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 month),'%Y-%m')
```

This should return all the records from the previous calendar month, as opposed to the records for the last 30 or 31 days.

Comment: I forgot to mention...this should return all the records from the previous calendar month, as opposed to the records for the last 30 or 31 days.

Comment: In my opinion this should be the accepted answer as it is simpler than the accepted answer yet provides the same result

Answer (score 4):

Even though the answer for this question has been selected already, however, I believe the simplest query will be

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE 
date_created BETWEEN (CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND CURRENT_DATE();
```

Comment: No, not quite. See my response to your comment on the answer given by @hobodave

Comment: @MattPassell You are right, I misunderstood the question.. I missed the point that result should be only limited to records ONLY from last month.

Answer (score 2):

```
WHERE created_date >= DATE_ADD(LAST_DAY(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH)), INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
  AND created_date <= DATE_ADD(LAST_DAY(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)), INTERVAL 0 DAY)
```

This worked for me (Selects all records created from last month, regardless of the day you run the query this month)

Answer (score 2):

Alternative with single condition

```sql
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE YEAR(date_created) * 12 + MONTH(date_created)
    = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE) * 12 + MONTH(CURRENT_DATE) - 1
```

Answer (score 1):

`select fields FROM table
WHERE date_created LIKE concat(LEFT(DATE_SUB(NOW(), interval 1 month),7),'%');`

this one will be able to take advantage of an index if your date_created is indexed, because it doesn't apply any transformation function to the field value.

Comment: @ggiroux - It does have to convert the date to a character type before applying the LIKE though.

Comment: yes indeed, but still an improvement over the selected answer IMHO (IFF date_created is indexed)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the query to get the records of the last month:

```
SELECT *
FROM `tablename`
WHERE `datefiled`
BETWEEN DATE_SUB( DATE( NOW( ) ) , INTERVAL 1
MONTH )
AND 
LAST_DAY( DATE_SUB( DATE( NOW( ) ) , INTERVAL 1
MONTH ) )
```

Regards
- saqib

Comment: Have you tried to run that query? As far as I see, it would not select all dates from the previous months (as in: return data from January throughout the whole February), but return data from a range starting the same day one month ago

Answer (score 1):

if you want to get orders from last month, you can try using

```
WHERE MONTH(order_date) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE()) -1
```

Comment: Please provide a complete SQL statement, when (trying) to answer a question.  (Also, I think, this answer is not very useful, when looking at the age and reputation of the accepted answer.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This will also return records from previous years if I am not mistaken

Answer (score 0):

One more way to do this in:

**MYSQL**

```
select * from <table_name> where date_created >= DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -30 DAY);
```

Answer (score 0):

A neater way I like to do it:

```
    SELECT * FROM table
    WHERE LAST_DAY(date_created) = LAST_DAY(now() - interval 1 month)
```

I doubt it would offer any performance benefits. So just personal preference.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT *  FROM table  
WHERE  YEAR(date_created) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
AND MONTH(date_created) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

Comment: Have you tried to run that query? As far as I see, it would not select all dates from the previous months (as in: return data from January throughout the whole February), but return data from a range starting the same day one month ago

Comment: i had make few changes , check now it's work or not