# Count rows order by last 12 months - PHP SQL

Tags: php, sql, count

I'm trying to count the number of rows, column(id) in my table details and display the last 12 months - ideally this will be a rolling 12 months, so it will display the current month and the previous 11. I have the following but it returns nothing:

```
    $sql = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date, '%m') as 'month',
COUNT(id) as 'total'
FROM details
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(date, '%m')
";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $con);

if (!$result) {
    echo "DB Error, could not query the database\n";
    echo 'MySQL Error: ' . mysql_error();
    exit;
}

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $row['month']. " = " .$row['total']. "<br />";
    }
```

I hope I have explained myself, if not please ask me...

Thanks for looking.

B.

Comment: Well, if the query is successful, nothing is echoed...

Comment: Durrr - always miss the obvious - one other question how do I limit to the last 12 months only, currently if returns all entries for month 1,2,3 etc

Comment: Well, the exact syntax depends on your RDBMS, but it should be possible to subtract an interval of one year from the current date.  Put that condition in a `where` clause.

Answer (score 0):

if you're using mssql, try the following query:

```
SELECT
    DATEADD(MM, DATEDIFF(MM, 0, date), 0) AS 'month',
    COUNT(1) as 'total'
FROM
    details
WHERE
    date >= DATEADD(MM, DATEDIFF(MM, 0, date) - 12, 0)
GROUP BY
    DATEADD(MM, DATEDIFF(MM, 0, date), 0)
```

For MySQL (extended from [MySQL: Query to get all rows from previous month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090221/mysql-query-to-get-all-rows-from-previous-month)) use the following `WHERE` clause

```
SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT(date, '%m') as 'month',
    COUNT(id) as 'total'
FROM
    details
WHERE
    YEAR(date) >= YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 12 MONTH)
AND MONTH(date) >= MONTH(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 12 MONTH)
GROUP BY
    DATE_FORMAT(date, '%m')
```

Comment: Thanks, but this returns:

DB Error, could not query the database MySQL Error: Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'DATEDIFF'

Comment: Ah, if you're using mysql the following link will get you started: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090221/mysql-query-to-get-all-rows-from-previous-month

Comment: Thanks @diaho , I can see the theory, but cannot get it to work within my example - could you edit your original to fit the new update?