# take records of the month following the month in progress with mysql

Tags: php, mysql, date

i'am new environment mysql .
I'd need to know how you can do to get all the records in a database registered in the previous month to the current month.

The database have the column data in this format 2015-10-02 .
And ' possible to get everyone in the month of September ?
I do this query every 15th of the month and take records of the previous month , everyone.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE YEAR(data) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
AND MONTH(data) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

Credit to @hobodave

Comment: write the date in that format ? to me with the format year- mm - dd is not working

Comment: That's the default format most people are using. yyyy-mm-dd. It works for me.

Comment: what value does the variable date ? you can make it as if I did today to take the record of September ? thanks

Comment: do you mean the variable "data". That's simply the column name in the database. In my case, my column name is "created_at". so my code would be `WHERE YEAR(created_at)...`

Comment: Mark my answer as the solution to mark your question as solved. all credit to user @hobodave.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090221/mysql-query-to-get-all-rows-from-previous-month

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, use the month() and year() functions to get the month and year parts of a date, and curdate() to get the current date.

```
select * from table
where month(date_field)=if(month(curdate())-1=0,12,month(curdate())-1)
and year(date_field)=if(month(curdate())-1=0,year(curdate())-1,year(curdate()))
```