# Select Orders of Last Month in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to write a query that selects Last month orders from a table  Order( id , ......., order_date).

Assume that the date of today is 4th of April. Will i select orders from 1st March to 31th of March or from the 4th of March to the 4th of April ???

Edit : 
The first query :

```
SELECT * from Order where order_date between sysdate() and sysdate - INTERVAL 1 Month
```

The Second Query :

```
     SELECT * from Order where order_date between (Last_day(sysdate()) - INETRVAL 1 MONTH) 
and ((Last_day(sysdate()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY) - INETRVAL 2 MONTH))
```

`(Last_day(sysdate()) - INETRVAL 1 MONTH)`  gives 30 of March

`((Last_day(sysdate()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY) - INETRVAL 2 MONTH))` gives 1st of March

Comment: Don't forget new year issues.

Comment: What are you asking about? Are you asking for a query? Or do you already have a query, and you aren't showing it?

Comment: We can't answer that question. You need to answer it or find the one who wants that and ask him/her

Comment: You need to find the last month of the year Try this link :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090221/mysql-query-to-get-all-rows-from-previous-month

Comment: I have edited,  from what i sad , do you vote for the first Query or the second Query ???

Comment: Last_day really isnt that useful in my opinion. Take great care with date ranges that you include the duration of the last day.

Comment: the order_day column have type DATE not DATETIME , but i think if we use BETWEEN the last day is Included   ( order_date between A and B ===  order_date >= A and order_date <= B )

Comment: `mysql> select order_date from t1 where order_date between ("2016-01-01") and ("2016-01-31");

+------------+
| order_date |

+------------+
| 2016-01-31 |
| 2016-01-30 |
| 2016-01-01 |
+------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)`

Comment: I'm with Nebi here. You say "I have to write a query that selects last month orders" and you've found out that "last month" is ambiguous. So ask the person who has you write the query what they mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Last month" typically means the whole period of the month prior to today. So if today was 4th April then last month is

```
 >= 1st March and < 1st April
```

E.g.

```
Select * from orders
Where order_date >= '2016-03-01' 
and order_date < '2016-04-01'
```

Note I recommend avoiding between for date ranges. Also note that the time of 23:59:59 is NOT the end of a day and that recent versions of mysql do support subsecond time precision.