# Ranking of the affiliates with most commissions from database

Tags: mysql

The table "commissions" is of this form:

```
affiliate   referral   amount       date
    3          2         15      2016-08-27
    1          22        10      2016-08-29
    4          45         5      2016-09-06
    1          33         9      2016-09-08
    3          17         4      2016-09-11
    2          33        10      2016-09-16
    1           9         7      2016-09-26
    3          17         9      2016-09-26
    2          69        10      2016-09-30
    1          21         7      2016-10-01
    4          55         2      2016-10-06
```

I need to find out the ranking of the affiliates with most commissions month to month.

I have tried:

```
SELECT affiliate, SUM(amount) as amount 
FROM commissions 
GROUP BY affiliate, YEAR(date), MONTH(date)
```

But unfortunately it is not throwing the desired results.

Please help.

Comment: Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090221/mysql-query-to-get-all-rows-from-previous-month?

Comment: Excelent! Thank you.

Comment: You do realize that `date` can't be both `> SOMEDATE'` and `< 'SOME_DATE'` at the same time, right? It can't be greater than and less than the same value.

Comment: Yes thanks for the observation, I will edit the question

Comment: You probably mean `MONTH(date), YEAR(date)` perhaps? If you're doing this frequently might want a field expressly for that purpose in the `YYYYMM` format.

Comment: Wouldn't the 'ranking' always be '1' ?!?