# MySQL Query to get all rows for 2 months ago

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to do a select where I can chose to see results for current month, previous month, 1 month ago, 2 months ago, 3 months ago.

I found this question: [MySQL: Query to get all rows from previous month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090221/mysql-query-to-get-all-rows-from-previous-month), but I'm stuck with a filter that will get me all the results for 2 months ago from first to last day of the month.

I tried with this but it doesn't work:

```
SELECT * FROM table
AND MONTH(date_created) = MONTH(1 MONTH - INTERVAL 2 MONTH);
```

Comment: If the date are stored using `date` datatype then you can use as `select * from table where date_created < date_sub(curdate(), interval 2 month);` if the date is saved as `datetime` or timestamp then use `now()` instead of `curdate()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE MONTH(date_created) = MONTH(NOW() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH)
    AND (
          YEAR(date_created) = YEAR(NOW()) 
        OR 
          YEAR(date_created) = YEAR(NOW() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH)
    );
```

Returning records CREATED PRIOR the last 2 months only in MySQL.

Comment: This solution may select all matching rows matching the specified month, from **any** year. http://stackoverflow.com/a/2090235/24378 This answer also filters based on the year.

Comment: Yup, added check of Current year so, it returns **only Last 2 Moths** back data

Comment: I guess AND YEAR(InsertedDate) should be AND YEAR(date_created)

Comment: yes buddy, I was checking it my database.. so remained as it is! Corrected now! （っ＾▿＾）

Comment: with the new year the query doesn't work i guess it should be fixed in AND YEAR(date_created) = YEAR(NOW() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH)

Answer (score 0):

You query have an error, correct one would be:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE MONTH(date_created) = MONTH(DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 2 MONTH))
```

For current month just MONTH(NOW()), replace "2" with any number of months you need (1,3,.. 23)

as mentioned in comments this solution ignores YEAR differences, it just selects all records with the same month, no matter the year

you can filter wrong year results with additional clause:

```
 AND YEAR(date_created) = '2019' # or year you need
```

Or use more complex query:

```
SELECT * FROM table
where
date_created between
/* first day of -2 month*/
date_sub(date_sub(now(),interval 2 month), interval (day(now())-1) day) 
and
/* last day of -2 month*/
last_day(date_sub(now(),interval 2 month))
```

Comment: Please do not post bare code, also provide an explanation for what the code is doing.

Comment: This answer shows how to use the filter, but doesn't answer the question

Comment: @fremail, the question was how to find results for 2 months ago (according to title), thought my answer was clean enough, provided explanation, do you think it's still not answering the question?

Comment: @2oppin, it's better now. But to be 100% sure it needs to check the year too ;-)

Comment: @fremail, happy now?)

Answer (score 0):

If you want all rows from 2 months ago, then use logic like this:

```
WHERE date_created >= DATE_SUB(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), 1 - DAY(CURDATE())), INTERVAL 2 MONTH) AND
      date_created < DATE_SUB(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), 1 - DAY(CURDATE())), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

What is this doing?  First, it is only applying functions to the current date part of the expression.  This allows MySQL to use an index on `date_created`, if available and appropriate.

The expression `DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), 1 - DAY(CURDATE())` is simply a way to get the first day of the month.