# How to get previous month in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

I can query my items from this month using:

```
MONTH(receivedOn) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE()) AND YEAR(receivedOn) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())
```

on `receivedOn`

How can I query previous month?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Query to get all rows from previous month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090221/query-to-get-all-rows-from-previous-month)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to check for the previous month by using `- INTERVAL 1 MONTH` in both `YEAR` and `MONTH` comparison as follows:

```
MONTH(receivedOn) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
AND YEAR(receivedOn) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```